# Sharepoint + VSTO deployment

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, vsto

I've developed a Word template in VSTO. When published it consits of several files including a Setup.exe, several msi files etc.

Due to the fact that my company's security policy won't allow me to store dlls and exes on the server I need an alternative way to provide all the necessary stuff to the end user.

I thoght it would be enough if I:

> 1) execute the setup.exe file on each client machine (it says everything got properly installed)
>
> 2) upload the xxx.dotm file to sharepoint and register it
>
> 3) edit policy settings

but it doesn't. When a user creates a new Document inside sharepoint using "New"->"xxx" the requested document loads without any error message and show the document but Word won't load any extensions / ribbons etc.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you hosting the assembly?
from what you have said so far.. you are hosting the DOTM file on sharepoint, and the custom assembly/ies locally on each client machine.
Not sure why you have chosen this approach, however to simply I would recommend you start by confirming your app works when all components are deployed locally.
If that works (then your app is fine and its just a deployment issue), try setting up a UNC share and putting the assembly/app files on the share, and the DOTM hosted in sharepoint.
check whether that works. if it doesn't your hitting an issue with CAS. refer to the MSDN document on network deployments of VSTO document apps.